# Tkz-berge graphs, equal arrows with unequal subfigures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-berge

In the following MWE (alas, it is not small):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\textwidth16cm
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {
shape = circle,
fill = black,
inner sep = 0pt,
outer sep = 0pt,
%minimum size = 8pt,
minimum size = 0pt,
draw}}
\SetGraphUnit{4}


\newbox{\BA}
\savebox{\BA}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {
shape = circle,
fill = black,
inner sep = 0pt,
outer sep = 0pt,
%minimum size = 8pt,
minimum size = 0pt,
draw}}


%\GraphInit[vstyle=Empty]
  \SetVertexNoLabel
  \begin{scope}[rotate=90,yscale=0.577] 
    \grCycle[prefix=v,RA=1]{4}
\grCycle[prefix=w,RA=0]{4}
%\EdgeDoubleMod{w}{4}{0}{1}%
%{v}{4}{0}{1}{4}
\Edges(v1,v3)
\end{scope}



%\draw (a2) node[below]{\textsf{a label}};
\draw (v0) node[above]{$g$};

\end{tikzpicture}}

\newbox{\BB}
\savebox{\BB}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {
shape = circle,
fill = black,
inner sep = 0pt,
outer sep = 0pt,
%minimum size = 8pt,
minimum size = 0pt,
draw}}


%\GraphInit[vstyle=Empty]
  \SetVertexNoLabel
  \begin{scope}[rotate=90,yscale=0.577]
    \grCycle[prefix=v,RA=1]{4}
\grCycle[prefix=w,RA=0]{4}
\EdgeDoubleMod{w}{4}{0}{1}%
{v}{4}{0}{1}{4}
\end{scope}



%\draw (a2) node[below]{\textsf{a label}};
\draw (v0) node[above]{$g$};
\draw (v1) node[left]{$y_{i+1}$};
\draw (v3) node[right]{$y_{1}$};
\draw (v2) node[below]{$v_{i}$};

\end{tikzpicture}}

\newbox{\BC}
\savebox{\BC}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {
shape = circle,
fill = black,
inner sep = 0pt,
outer sep = 0pt,
%minimum size = 8pt,
minimum size = 0pt,
draw}}
  \SetVertexNoLabel
%\grEmptyPath[Math,prefix=p,RA=2,RS=0]{5}
%\grEmptyPath[Math,prefix=q,RA=2,RS=3]{5}
\grPath[Math,prefix=p,RA=1,RS=0]{3}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0.5 cm]
\grPath[Math,prefix=q,RA=1,RS=1]{3}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\SetGraphUnit{1}
\NO(q1){rd}
\SO(p1){dol}
\end{scope}

\Edges(p0,q0,p1,q1,p2,q2,rd,q0)
\Edges(p1,dol)
\Edges(q1,rd)
\Edges(p0,dol,p2)

\draw (rd) node[above]{$g$};
\draw (dol) node[below]{$v_i$};
\draw (p0) node[left]{$y_{i+1}$};
\draw (p2) node[right]{$y_{i}$};
\draw (q0) node[left]{$x_{i+1}$};
\draw (q2) node[right]{$x_{i}$};



\end{tikzpicture}%
}
%[\Delta_5^1,d,D_5^1]$
%
%


\newbox{\BD}
\savebox{\BD}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {
shape = circle,
fill = black,
inner sep = 0pt,
outer sep = 0pt,
%minimum size = 8pt,
minimum size = 0pt,
draw}}

  \SetVertexNoLabel
%\grEmptyPath[Math,prefix=p,RA=2,RS=0]{5}
%\grEmptyPath[Math,prefix=q,RA=2,RS=3]{5}
\grPath[Math,prefix=p,RA=1,RS=0]{2}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0.5 cm]
\grPath[Math,prefix=q,RA=1,RS=1]{2}
\grPath[Math,prefix=n,RA=1,RS=-1]{1}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1 cm]
\grPath[Math,prefix=r,RA=1,RS=2]{1}
\end{scope}
\Edges(q1,r0,p0,p1,q0,q1,p1)
\Edges(p0,n0,p1)

\draw (r0) node[above]{$g$};
\draw (p0) node[left]{$y_{i+1}$};
\draw (p1) node[right]{$y_{i}$};
\draw (q0) node[left]{$x_{i+1}$};
\draw (q1) node[right]{$x_{i}$};

\draw (n0) node[below]{$v_{i}$};

\end{tikzpicture}%
}
%$[\Delta_6^0,d,D_6^0]$
%
%


\GraphInit[vstyle=Empty]
\Vertex[NoLabel]{Asr}
\WE[L=\usebox{\BA}](Asr){AA}
\NO[L=\usebox{\BB}](Asr){AB}
\EA[L=\usebox{\BC}](Asr){AC}
\SO[L=\usebox{\BD}](Asr){AD}
\SetUpEdge[style={->},labelstyle={above,xshift=-3mm,yshift=1mm}]
\Edges[label=$C_i$](AA,AB)
\SetUpEdge[style={->},labelstyle={above,xshift=3mm,yshift=1mm}]
\Edges[label=$A$](AA,AD)

\SetUpEdge[style={<-},labelstyle={above,xshift=3mm,yshift=1mm}]
\Edges[label=$A$](AC,AB)
\SetUpEdge[style={<-},labelstyle={above,xshift=-3mm,yshift=1mm}]
\Edges[label=$\bar{C_i}$](AC,AD)
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{comment}


Fig. 8 b.


\end{document}
```

[image]

I have unequal arrows connecting subfigures. Is there a possibility of obtaining equal arrows connecting this subfigures with different dimensions? The length of an arrow should be at least such as of this with $A$ over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parallel and equal-length arrows I would normally go with `tikz-cd`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm} % maybe use the package `geometry` for such things. 16 cm do not fit in article...
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{%
    ,VertexStyle/.style = {%
        ,shape = circle
        ,inner sep = 0pt
        ,fill=black
        ,draw
        }
    }
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzcd}[%
    ,column sep={3cm,between origins}
    ,row sep={3cm,between origins}
    ,every arrow/.append style={%
        ,thick
        ,shorten >= 1.5cm
        ,shorten <= 1.5cm
        ,start anchor=center
        ,end anchor=center
        }
    ]
    & \begin{tikzpicture}
    \SetVertexNoLabel
    \begin{scope}[rotate=90,yscale=0.577]
    \grCycle[prefix=v,RA=1]{4}
    \grCycle[prefix=w,RA=0]{4}
    \EdgeDoubleMod{w}{4}{0}{1}%
    {v}{4}{0}{1}{4}
    \end{scope}

    \draw (v0) node[above]{$g$};
    \draw (v1) node[left]{$y_{i+1}$};
    \draw (v3) node[right]{$y_{1}$};
    \draw (v2) node[below]{$v_{i}$};    
    \end{tikzpicture} \arrow{dr}{A} & \\
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
        \SetVertexNoLabel
        \begin{scope}[rotate=90,yscale=0.577] 
        \grCycle[prefix=v,RA=1]{4}
        \grCycle[prefix=w,RA=0]{4}
        \Edges(v1,v3)
        \end{scope}

        \draw (v0) node[above]{$g$};        
    \end{tikzpicture} \arrow{dr}{A}\arrow{ur}{C_i}
    & &
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \SetVertexNoLabel
    \grPath[Math,prefix=p,RA=1,RS=0]{3}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=0.5 cm]
    \grPath[Math,prefix=q,RA=1,RS=1]{3}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
    \SetGraphUnit{1}
    \NO(q1){rd}
    \SO(p1){dol}
    \end{scope}

    \Edges(p0,q0,p1,q1,p2,q2,rd,q0)
    \Edges(p1,dol)
    \Edges(q1,rd)
    \Edges(p0,dol,p2)

    \draw (rd) node[above]{$g$};
    \draw (dol) node[below]{$v_i$};
    \draw (p0) node[left]{$y_{i+1}$};
    \draw (p2) node[right]{$y_{i}$};
    \draw (q0) node[left]{$x_{i+1}$};
    \draw (q2) node[right]{$x_{i}$};    
    \end{tikzpicture} \\
    & 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \SetVertexNoLabel
    \grPath[Math,prefix=p,RA=1,RS=0]{2}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=0.5 cm]
    \grPath[Math,prefix=q,RA=1,RS=1]{2}
    \grPath[Math,prefix=n,RA=1,RS=-1]{1}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=1 cm]
    \grPath[Math,prefix=r,RA=1,RS=2]{1}
    \end{scope}
    \Edges(q1,r0,p0,p1,q0,q1,p1)
    \Edges(p0,n0,p1)

    \draw (r0) node[above]{$g$};
    \draw (p0) node[left]{$y_{i+1}$};
    \draw (p1) node[right]{$y_{i}$};
    \draw (q0) node[left]{$x_{i+1}$};
    \draw (q1) node[right]{$x_{i}$};    
    \draw (n0) node[below]{$v_{i}$};    
    \end{tikzpicture} \arrow{ur}{\bar{C_i}} &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{figure}    
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

It is quite difficult to find something nice, as the figures are that different in size. You might want to add the `shorten` manually to each arrow.

[image]

Comment: It is close to my expectations (+1), but now I want to enlarge the distance between arrows and $x_{i+1}$ (and $x_i$).

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Isn't it enough to enlarge the distance between origins and to shorten a bit more? If not, you will have to set the position manually to the arrows such as `\arrow[shift left=3ex]{dr}{A}`.